# TypeError: Cannot read property 'cases' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to build a website in react.js. I called an api and there are some property in this api. When I called any property, faced error message. I want to show "cases" property in my website but when try to access "case" property form state then this error comes"TypeError: Cannot read property 'cases' of undefined"

My code

```
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import CardDeck from "react-bootstrap/CardDeck";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [latest, setLatest] = useState();
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios 
       .get("https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/all")
       .then (res=>{ 
         setLatest(res.data);

       })
       .catch(err=>{
         console.log(err);
       })
  })
  
  return (
    <div>
      <CardDeck>
        <Card
          bg="secondary"
          text="white"
          className="text-center"
          style={{ margin: "10px"}}
        >
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>Cases</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>{latest.cases}</Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
          <Card.Footer>
            <small>Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
          </Card.Footer>
        </Card>
```

Error message

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cases' of undefined
App
C:/webdevelopment/project/covid/src/App.js:34
  31 | >
  32 |   <Card.Body>
  33 |     <Card.Title>Cases</Card.Title>
> 34 |     <Card.Text>{latest.cases}</Card.Text>
     | ^  35 |   </Card.Body>
  36 |   <Card.Footer>
  37 |     <small>Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
View compiled
```

api

```
{
"updated": 1599367649631,
"cases": 27065812,
"todayCases": 11648,
"deaths": 883742,
"todayDeaths": 566,
"recovered": 19166178,
"todayRecovered": 10236,
"active": 7015892,
"critical": 60720,
"casesPerOneMillion": 3472,
"deathsPerOneMillion": 113.4,
"tests": 536587691,
"testsPerOneMillion": 69041.61,
"population": 7771946760,
"oneCasePerPeople": 0,
"oneDeathPerPeople": 0,
"oneTestPerPeople": 0,
"activePerOneMillion": 902.72,
"recoveredPerOneMillion": 2466.07,
"criticalPerOneMillion": 7.81,
"affectedCountries": 215
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your `useState` variable. Try this:

```
const [latest, setLatest] = useState({ cases: "" });
```

**Explanation**
Before hitting the api, when react tries to render your component that time `{latest.cases}` throws error as `latest` insn't initialized and hence takes the value of `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the initial value to empty object
`const [latest, setLatest] = useState({});`
as  you are waiting for response from the api your state is undefined

Answer (score 0):

please usState as below:

```
const [latest,useLatest]=useState(null);
```

and in the render part:

```
<Card.Text>{latest && latest.cases}</Card.Text>
```

The above code will failsafe if latest is not being set and render gets triggered before that, which is the case of useEffect.